# using brand as a feature in product categorization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on classifying  products into categories  using scikit-learn , I have trained a logistic regression model which has done well. I want to improve the performance of the classifier and I have been wondering if the brand of the product could have an impact on improving the classification. As you know in the pipeline of a classifier there are steps like stemming and tokenization etc so is there a way to add brand treatment as an extra feature to the pipeline so that the algorithm can used to classify products? 
The data I am using is a dataset of products(title,brand,description etc...) with their categories as labels.

code:

```
with open('file_path') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

def train(classifier, X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=33)
    print("X_train:")
    print(len(X_train))
    print("X_test:")
    print(len(X_test))
    print("y_train:")
    print(len(y_train))
    print("y_test:")
    print(len(y_test))
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print "Accuracy: %s" % classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
    return classifier



target = np.asarray(d["target"])
data=d["data"]
categs=d["categs"]

trial = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=stemming_tokenizer,
                             stop_words=stopwords.words('french') + list(string.punctuation))),
    ('classifier', linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e2,n_jobs=-1)),
])

print("start train...")
clf=train(trial, data, target)
print("finished train")
```

Comment: Please provide a code or pseudocode example of what you are trying to do and where your issues are.

Comment: @Fabien I have done some modification. I hope my problem is clear right now.